# Pandas, how to apply changes dataframe with groupby() / conditional function calling?

Tags: pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have a huge timeseries dataframe with over 1m rows. It has list of monthly stock returns and I'd like to create a new row to track the rolling sum of 3 previous months. The dataframe has all company A rows first, then all company B rows, then all company C rows...

For example:

```
          date                COMNAM    PRC    RET
395 2017-02-28       GAS NATURAL INC 12.650  0.000
396 2017-03-31       GAS NATURAL INC 12.700  0.010
397 2017-04-28       GAS NATURAL INC 12.500 -0.016
398 2017-05-31       GAS NATURAL INC 12.700  0.016
399 2017-06-30       GAS NATURAL INC 12.925  0.024
400 2017-07-31       GAS NATURAL INC 12.950  0.002
401 2017-08-31       GAS NATURAL INC    nan    nan
402 1985-12-31                   NaN    nan    nan
403 1986-01-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 11.625    nan
404 1986-02-28  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 13.250  0.140
405 1986-03-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 14.188  0.071
406 1986-04-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 14.938  0.053
407 1986-05-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 14.625 -0.021
408 1986-06-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 12.688 -0.132
409 1986-07-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 13.312  0.049
410 1986-08-29  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 13.312  0.000
411 1986-09-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 14.250  0.070
412 1986-10-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 13.375 -0.061
413 1986-11-28  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 13.375  0.000
414 1986-12-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP 12.375 -0.075
```

The rolling()-function would give me the sum of 3 previous months, but that would include the last returns of the previous stock for the first dates of each company. I have a feeling the groupby() function might be able to help, but I'm kinda stuck on how. Or am I overthinking it, and there is some better way where I don't even need the groupby?

Comment: Please don't put images in as your data, we need to then retype it to get it into a dataframe at our end...

Comment: Thanks. That's good point I didn't really think of. I now swapped the image with actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute the rolling sum of 3 **previous** months (**without** the
current month), for two columns of interest, from the current group of
rows, define the following function:

```
def mySum(grp):
    return grp[['PRC', 'RET']].shift().rolling(3).sum()
```

Then, to get such rolling sums for each group (company), run:

```
result = df.join(df[df.COMNAM.notnull()].groupby('COMNAM').apply(mySum)\
    .reset_index(level=0, drop=True).add_prefix('r'))
```

The result is a join between the current *df* and the result of invocation
of the above function for each group (company).
Column names of the intermediate result are prepended with *r*, to mark
the rolling sum.

For your data sample the result is:

```
         date                COMNAM     PRC    RET    rPRC   rRET
0  2017-02-28       GAS NATURAL INC  12.650  0.000     NaN    NaN
1  2017-03-31       GAS NATURAL INC  12.700  0.010     NaN    NaN
2  2017-04-28       GAS NATURAL INC  12.500 -0.016     NaN    NaN
3  2017-05-31       GAS NATURAL INC  12.700  0.016  37.850 -0.006
4  2017-06-30       GAS NATURAL INC  12.925  0.024  37.900  0.010
5  2017-07-31       GAS NATURAL INC  12.950  0.002  38.125  0.024
6  2017-08-31       GAS NATURAL INC     NaN    NaN  38.575  0.042
7  1985-12-31                   NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN
8  1986-01-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  11.625    NaN     NaN    NaN
9  1986-02-28  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  13.250  0.140     NaN    NaN
10 1986-03-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  14.188  0.071     NaN    NaN
11 1986-04-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  14.938  0.053  39.063    NaN
12 1986-05-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  14.625 -0.021  42.376  0.264
13 1986-06-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  12.688 -0.132  43.751  0.103
14 1986-07-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  13.312  0.049  42.251 -0.100
15 1986-08-29  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  13.312  0.000  40.625 -0.104
16 1986-09-30  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  14.250  0.070  39.312 -0.083
17 1986-10-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  13.375 -0.061  40.874  0.119
18 1986-11-28  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  13.375  0.000  40.937  0.009
19 1986-12-31  MOBILE NATIONAL CORP  12.375 -0.075  41.000  0.009
```

If you want to "ignore" *NaN* values (treat them as *0*), change the
function to:

```
def mySum(grp):
    return grp[['PRC', 'RET']].fillna(0).shift().rolling(3).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, although this was not exactly what I wanted, it gave me good ideas how to proceed and work with the function.